# Open and work on Mulesoft Project from repository

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft

I want to open the Mule project from a repository folder that contains the project with the following folder structure.

I am doing this so I can commit the changes of the project straight to the repository (so others can also download the changes) without having to export and import the project as a zip file every time.

I am getting the following error message and Mulesoft also overwrites the mule.xml file to a blank file.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this from happening?

[workspace print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqwRn.png)

[option when importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npAxV.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOQiR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to carry `mule-project.xml`, `.classpath` and `.project` files in the repository in case that you are not using Maven.

Please check / share your gitignore file. Also check the [Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GybJf.png), there should be description of what is missing.